# Why is my email being marked SPAM by gmail?

Tags: email, email-server, spam-marked

I'm running my own mail server in a VPS using iRedMail. I followed all the steps to get a good mail record like setting SPF, DKIM and SMARC values. When I try to send to my gmail account 'openplantsolutions@gmail.com', Gmail accounts the email as a spam. Below is the original message taken from gmail. According to Gmail:

- SPF: PASS with IP 139.99.169.193
- DKIM:    'PASS' with domain open-plant.com
- DMARC:   'PASS'

Any help? Thanks

> Delivered-To: openplantsolutions@gmail.com Received: by 10.46.57.13
>   with SMTP id g13csp1434134lja;
>           Sun, 1 Apr 2018 01:41:09 -0700 (PDT) X-Google-Smtp-Source: AIpwx48UCkYJYT2wHIlZdhPxCRKc/ys+AUGxE/RVSahjhu/qjye4JPUzlkyNJRPgxobdwiDTS1Fi
>   X-Received: by 10.98.102.131 with SMTP id
>   s3mr4089260pfj.89.1522572068895;
>           Sun, 01 Apr 2018 01:41:08 -0700 (PDT) ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1522572068; cv=none;
>           d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
>           b=kOGFrsw6/wJLxIReIL12wZeYZdk0OAXmYPoHADnQu/kPyaII5IBkjiJtVq1ectxgKb
>            fyuyxIgDPtEiL3kIS3Sd8EX7Z/UmnuRXgU0fZulaqYEHPTmjYX13gte7jIwyFt9xrmS+
>            upP350D6r/e78fZ59VQEBn/EpiEXzx5qXzrs+5rHJL4Q0Hx85iubcRCrTuAZTL1G7fMW
>            S+L0ICNB6FdVGtavEJ/kkO9HQ8WiFMMXl8sjO5njZ6Y69bWHwQmUdvxGGQJqZ/tCZl7i
>            IivD3F+RBTy0g+eNUPPS3QAuE137VpH/hOpebbqvCnQ1v6L6uehoClLWnxE0uaWygYtH
>            9HpQ== ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
>           h=message-id:content-transfer-encoding:subject:date:to:from
>            :mime-version:dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
>           bh=bn7+s34wuVRWkhEjP3SOwwkq3H72XHOcSfQ+Jjevh/g=;
>           b=Hrl5BtIzDaI2afnGo3cdr5R6wuyGGYYED1X4SvIxA+9xFC7sbNJ2eaYOah6PkCNhEz
>            N7uqJeVr+uJyPC+p60uUW/HeUSxk/ofF/HedNh+/3MVSI5xg3plevJ6Rcr7VGUHWvrmK
>            P45pybSIgacboyXjm0yI4u6nWSE3SR7q+7SJB6e9D7UlD9vpW+H1cxqSdU1tNlvhypNX
>            lXQmFXShYI0BTBknI6ZZPSULTSC/S7YAJNNaalHwZLTX/A3PouRPm5uyzg+libCIILhI
>            RDGtqb8agegys/Z73WpODRtTr8VcvGJ/Q/uyr5cPfPPmplrBbWUdwdcQGp2idlpmX/L0
>            Au4Q== ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
>          dkim=pass header.i=@open-plant.com header.s=dkim header.b=p6W2jXTI;
>          spf=pass (google.com: domain of hairextensionspecialistperth@open-plant.com designates 139.99.169.193
>   as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mailfrom=hairextensionspecialistperth@open-plant.com;
>          dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=open-plant.com Return-Path:  Received:
>   from mail.open-plant.com (mail.open-plant.com. [139.99.169.193])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id q2si8171457pgc.401.2018.04.01.01.41.08
>           for 
>           (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
>           Sun, 01 Apr 2018 01:41:08 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of hairextensionspecialistperth@open-plant.com
>   designates 139.99.169.193 as permitted sender)
>   client-ip=139.99.169.193; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          dkim=pass header.i=@open-plant.com header.s=dkim header.b=p6W2jXTI;
>          spf=pass (google.com: domain of hairextensionspecialistperth@open-plant.com designates 139.99.169.193
>   as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mailfrom=hairextensionspecialistperth@open-plant.com;
>          dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=open-plant.com Received: from vps176044.vps.ovh.ca (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by
>   mail.open-plant.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id D43607F31E for
>   ; Sun,   1 Apr 2018 10:41:06 +0200
>   (CEST) Authentication-Results: vps176044.vps.ovh.ca (amavisd-new);
>   dkim=pass (1024-bit key) reason="pass (just generated, assumed good)"
>   header.d=open-plant.com DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256;
>   c=relaxed/simple; d=open-plant.com;
>   h=content-transfer-encoding:content-type:content-type:subject
>   :subject:date:date:to:from:from:mime-version; s=dkim; t= 1522572066;
>   x=1523436067; bh=6VMYMtWMt/JbToNyl363VUxznq1GyZUepKW Tv0hWYy8=;
>   b=p6W2jXTIlVNpi5v0/FwX8/n0BZEA2+DiGyyn4hHmavqiX1PFhQo
>   UNsLxwbBwjh9pmZK2lBxUf9pTkgZAWfVyqlv3cFsQj2Tp8Jc2zrorutfIpj3RJ8o
>   HMKhSnsVRzPYZhheLpjbzZx7VbomLaqGXi5eRzaAdq9KPUu7Y8yAGBmE=
>   X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at open-plant.com X-Spam-Flag: NO
>   X-Spam-Score: 2.094 X-Spam-Level: ** X-Spam-Status: No, score=2.094
>   tagged_above=2 required=6.31 tests=[ALL_TRUSTED=-1,
>   HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG=0.635, MIME_HTML_ONLY=1.105,
>   MISSING_MID=0.14, TVD_RCVD_SINGLE=1.213] autolearn=no
>   autolearn_force=no Received: from mail.open-plant.com ([127.0.0.1]) by
>   vps176044.vps.ovh.ca (vps176044.vps.ovh.ca [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new,
>   port 10026) with ESMTP id KBPnmKoABbD2 for
>   ; Sun,   1 Apr 2018 10:41:06 +0200
>   (CEST) Received: from AZRINLAPTOP (cor9-ppp5856.bur.dsl.connect.net.au
>   [210.10.146.14]) by mail.open-plant.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id
>   79D497F31C for ; Sun,   1 Apr 2018
>   10:41:06 +0200 (CEST) MIME-Version: 1.0 From:
>   hairextensionspecialistperth@open-plant.com To:
>   openplantsolutions@gmail.com Date: 1 Apr 2018 16:41:06 +0800 Subject:
>   We will contact you back shortly! Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>   Message-Id: <20180401084106.D43607F31E@mail.open-plant.com>
>
> ## Thank you for booking. We will contact you shortly
>
> A
>   booking re= quest was made by YOU with the following
>   details:
> Name: qwertt
> Co= ntact: 04333222
> Email:
>   openplantsolutions@gmail.com
> Personal Mess= age:
> HEY  THIS
>   IS NEW

Comment: Maybe try to test your mail server with [this](https://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx). Just to be sure you didn't misconfigure it somehow.